# How to filter data from Sqlite IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Hi i am using following library for sqlite implementation in my project.

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

In my sqlite i am storing huge amount of data from there i am filtering my values. This is my tried code.

```
let user = self.usersTable.filter(self.id == textfild.text!)

        do {
            for row in try self.database.prepare(user) {
                print("id: \(row[self.id]), code: \(row[self.email])")

            }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

this code is working if the two values are same ex: ( 171(self.id value) == 171 )(textfield value) but i am looking for if i enter "17" it should shows all related data in sqlite.

user[self.id].localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(textfild.text) i tried this but its not working.

Comment: Have you looked at `like` or `match` for text searches? If `id` is a number you might need to convert it to a string first though. [Filtering doc](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#filtering-rows)

Comment: @Joakim Danielson id is in string format only. i tried like and match i couldn't able to get how to use those methods.